# Call Python function from another script?

Tags: python, virtualenv

I want to call a function in `a.py` from `b.py`. I am running this in a virtual environment.

`a.py` is located at `/home/user/admin/`, and so in `b.py` I have

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/user/admin')
from a import my_function
```

But when I run it I get

```
from a import my_function
ImportError: No module named my_function
```

Why isn't it finding the module?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are running your script from within a virtualenv you may need to change the current working directory like this:

```
import os
filepath = os.path.realpath(__file__)
dirname = os.path.dirname(filepath)
os.chdir(dirname)

from a import my_function
# do stuff
```

Also you could try using a **package** with the following

- Create a `__init__.py` in `/home/user/admin/` any folder with a file like this its recognized by python as a package. This file can be empty.
- Next you can import a from b like this:

  ```
  from .a import my_function
  ```

This is a **relative import**, basically what you do is to tell the interpreter to import `a` from current package which is referenced by the dot. More details [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#id9)

As a side note, don't harcode the file current path, instead use something like this:

```
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(__file__)) # in your case would be /home/user/admin
```

Comment: does there need to be anything in `__init__.py`? and why did you add a "." infront of a?

Comment: OP isn't trying to make a package, but actually append to the path, `__init__.py` isn't relevant here (unless you want to suggest using a package and explain how)

Comment: @jamesbrown it's called a relative import, details [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#id9)